# NHibernate Linq : how to use StartsWith on an integer type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

I'd like to execute a query like this but it fails :

```
session.Linq<Product>().Where(p=>p.Id.ToString().StartsWith("123"))
```

Is there a workaround ? I'd prefer to use LINQ... maybe there is a easy way to extend the linq provider ?

I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2

EDIT: Yes, it fails because NHIbernate.Linq doesn't handle ToString()

Comment: This is a sign that your field should be a string.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why on earth are you looking for Id values that "start with" a 1?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, probably: there's a textbox that a user has typed "1" into, and is preparing to type the next digit, but between those keystrokes - a developer wants to run some IO in the database.

Comment: @David B: yes, that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to do this, what you might want to do is create a parallel column that could be the string version of your key. Using NHibernate interceptors, a database trigger, or a host of other options would keep the field updated and in sync without muddying up your code.

I think I would avoid doing this, but that is one way you could go.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest thing to do but instead of updating the paralel column in an interceptor I could simply update it in the setter of the first column.

Comment: Actually, you don't *need* a separate DB column: you can use a Formula. The disadvantage is that it can't be indexed.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon : that is the best solution for me, thank you, I didn't know about NHibernate formulas

Comment: Depending on the row count, especially for something that's 'find as you type' an index is really really going to be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) in the comments that if you need string comparison on the product Id field, then it should be a `char` or `varchar` field to begin with.

Is the number of digits in a product Id constant? In that case you could write something like:

```
session.Linq<Product>().Where(p=>p.Id >= 10000 && p.Id < 20000)
```

Even if you don't know the number of digits, you could write

```
session.Linq<Product>().Where(p=> 
    (p.Id >= 10 && p.Id < 20) || 
    (p.Id >= 100 && p.Id < 200) || 
    (p.Id >= 1000 && p.Id < 2000) || 
    (p.Id >= 10000 && p.Id < 20000) || ... );
```

Well, it's ugly, but it will work :-)

By the way, you can get the first digit in T-SQL by using the following expression:

```
(Product.Id / POWER(10, FLOOR(LOG10(Product.Id))))
```

However, I don't think the Linq provider of NHibernate 2.1.2 is able to map the .Net math functions to corresponding T-SQL functions. You could give it a try:

```
session.Linq<Product>().Where(p => p.Id / Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(p.Id))) == 1)
```

Comment: The multi interval code could even use an index(I don't know about if specific DB servers do) whereas it'd require unrealistic understanding of math to use an index with the last code.

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade to NHibernate 3, you can [extend the LINQ provider](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html) so it recognizes an expression like `p.Id.NumberStartsWith(1)` (this will wrap any of the approaches suggested as answers to this question)

It's a *little bit* of work, but once it's done, the client code will look pretty nice.

Plus, you'll have a lot of fun :-)

Comment: It's a very good suggestion but the project is already in production and wouldn't be wise to change the NHibernate version now

Answer (score 1):

The query likely fails because NHibernate does not know how to translate a ToString() (or the various parses) to CAST/CONVERT methods.

I agree with Elian and SLaks - if you need a single "character" out of the product ID, this ID should be a varchar. There is no truly elegant way to get this query to work otherwise; if it were a string, the StartsWith() function would be converted to a `ProductId LIKE 'x%'` condition with little fuss.